# How to update a whole column based on a HTTP call done on each cell?

Tags: pandas

I am fumbling around with Pandas (I want to avoid using Excel, I have very basic knowledge of Pandas and a reasonable of Python), trying to add a column based on another column.

Specifically, I have a column with IDs, and I want to enrich my data by making a HTTP query to an API and using a field in the JSON response:

```py
d['m0'] = pd.read_json(f"http://localhost:3000/{d['id']}")['H']['M0']
```

What I wanted to say in the above was

> take the data from a cell in the column `id`, run the API query, and put the `['H']['M0']` of the JSON response (a string) into the column `m0`

What I get  is

```
InvalidURL                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 d['m0'] = pd.read_json(f"http://localhost:3000/{d['id']}")['H']['M0']
```

I feel that the way th eURI was built is not correct, i.e. the content of the **cell** for column `id` was not used, but rather **the whole column**:

```
InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. '/0       AA13\n1       BB10\n2
```

`AA13`, `BB10`, ...are the ids in the column

Comment: You are appending the entire "id" column of dataframe to the URL. For trial, just access the first element like this `f"http://localhost:3000/{d['id'][0]}"`. For a long term solution, we need to understand what you want to achieve by creating URL from dataframe column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you have various ID values and you want to automate it by fetching the JSON corresponding to that ID and use values from JSON to further populate the dataframe.

I have not seen the structure of your JSON or return type of accessed fields; but I feel that you are looking for following:

```py
d['m0'] = d['id'].apply(lambda id: pd.read_json(f"http://localhost:3000/{id}")['H']['M0'])
```